# How to rename partitions in the system?

Tags: rename

I migrated from windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04. Two of my drives were named in Windows. But two drives had the default name. Now in Ubuntu the partitions which had default names in Windows are named 107 GB Filesystem. This is very confusing to me. Both are NTFS file systems. Is there a way I can rename those file systems to avoid confusion? i tried many forums and could not find any answer.

Comment: Have you tried disk utility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done easily using Disc Utility

First open Disk Utility.

Select the partition you wish to re-name.

Next click `Edit File System Label`

Enter your password as prompted.

Change the name as required and click apply.

Answer (score 1):

GParted can set the label on a partition.

Comment: I recommend editing this to provide specific instructions (and maybe even a screenshot) showing how to set a volume label with GParted.

Answer (score 0):

You can change name with disk utility. open it first select partition. unmount it first and Rename it..otherwise you have dual boot system... open windows give partitions names like C:/ : Windows D:/ :data. Names will be appaer in ubuntu